# Regular expression in PHP to extract minutes and seconds values

Tags: php, regex

I have the following section of HTML markup...

```
<div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 157px; padding: 16px 0px 16px 0px;">
    <p class="sectionHdr">The page you requested is currently unavailable because the statistics are being updated.</p>
    <p class="sectionHdr">The statistics update will finish in about&nbsp;48 minutes 39 seconds.</p>
</div>
```

What's the PHP code to extract the minutes and seconds values using a regular expression please?

I could do it with string manipulation, but I'd prefer to do it with a regular expression, I've just never been able to wrap my head around them!

Comment: Something like this? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iW7

Comment: I was hoping to get "48" and "39" out separately, if that's possible?

Comment: Like this? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iW9 What did you actually try yourself?

Comment: That looks like it would also work. I'd tied myself in knots and got no where, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robbie I've managed to figure out this will work... [http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iWb](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iW8).

It's not quite as flexible as I was imagining, but it'll do the trick.

RegExp is:

```
/(\d+) minutes (\d+) seconds/
```

Comment: Glad you've found a solution. You should use `+` to match _at least one_ digit instead of `*` which will match zero or more digits - also you should post the regex that you've found to solve your problem as part of your answer :)